# Why is the movie named Maratonci trče počasni krug (in English The Marathon Family)?

Tags: title, the-marathon-family

The literal meaning of [*The Marathon Family*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084302/)'s original title, *Maratonci trče počasni krug*, could be translated as something like *"Marathoners running a lap of honor"*. How does the title correspond to the movie?

Answer (score 1):

Movie title is ironic because Marathoners run 42,195 km (in standard race) and they don't have the energy to run the lap of honor. Movie is black comedy so title fits. Marathoners are sixs generations of family Topalović. Movie ends in bloodshed, so its their "final lap".